# Problems setting up react-i18next with NextJs 13 for component localization

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, next.js13, react-i18next

I'm digging into NextJS 13 and I need to understand a simple use case for i18next:

My goal is only to translate components, both server and client side, as simple as:

```
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const MyComponent  = () => {
  return <p>{t('msg')}</p>
}


export default MyComponent;
```

I'm using the new app routing mechanism and I need to have the following directory structure:

```
app
 |------ about
 |------ home
components
 |------- MyComponent
locale
 |------- en
 |        |---- MyComponent.json
 |------- de
 |        |---- MyComponent.json
```

Basically I want to keep dictionary files in the locale folder and I don't want to use the `app->[lang]->page` schema.

Is it possible to be done using NextJS 13?
Using NextJs 13, am I tied to the `app->[lang]->page` structure?

Well, to move on and learn by doing, I've installed react-i18next together with i18next and tried to setup a simple project:

My i18n.js config:

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

// the translations
// (tip move them in a JSON file and import them,
// or even better, manage them separated from your code: https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files)
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: {
      "msg": "Welcome to React and react-i18next"
    }
  },
  fr: {
    translation: {
      "msg": "Bienvenue à React et react-i18next"
    }
  }
};

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: "en", // language to use, more information here: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#languages-namespaces-resources
    // you can use the i18n.changeLanguage function to change the language manually: https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage
    // if you're using a language detector, do not define the lng option

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
    }
  });

  export default i18n;
```

When running I got the following error:

```
./src/app/i18n.js
ReactServerComponentsError:

You're importing a component that needs createContext. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.

   ,-[/Users/mnd/dev/node_modules/react-i18next/dist/es/context.js:1:1]
 1 | import { createContext } from 'react';
   :          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 2 | import { getDefaults, setDefaults } from './defaults.js';
 3 | import { getI18n, setI18n } from './i18nInstance.js';
 4 | import { initReactI18next } from './initReactI18next.js';
   `----

The error was caused by importing 'react-i18next/dist/es/index.js' in './src/app/i18n.js'.

Maybe one of these should be marked as a client entry with "use client":
  ./src/app/i18n.js
  ./src/app/page.tsx
```

I'm completely lost on where to go from this error... not sure, but it seens that NextJs 13 does not support `context` because of the server components. If not, how can I use react-i18next on the way I need to?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change in your i18n.js config import

```
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
```

to

```
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next/initReactI18next";
```